How to use dark background support with lesspipe?
I got lesspipe installed and enabled with export LESSOPEN=|/opt/homebrew/bin/lesspipe.sh %s and it works well.
The problem I'm facing is that my iTerm2 has a dark background, and I don't see a way to pass through a --style flag to the pygmentize script that's being used by lesspipe.
Looking through the pytmentize CLI source code, I can only see that it looks at TERM and COLORTERM environment variable.
Is there a nice way to set the style used by Pygmentise through lessopen.sh?
